# Is there a "recommended" way to choose the neighbours in a local search algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

For my programming project I need to implement a local search algorithm. The generic local search algorithm is easy to understand but the thing I am most struggling with is how to deal with the neighbourhood.

It seems that when you implement such an algorithm, you don't explicitly state the neighbourhood but you declare a neighbourhood relation which tells you what you are allowed to modify in your present solution to get a "neighbour" or how two neighbours differ.

So lets say I have such a neighbourhood relation and a starting solution. What I first thought about was to make this purely random. Take the starting solution S. I would then call something like neighbour(S) which randomly chooses a neighbour and then you would start comparing...

How common is it to choose the neighbour systematically? I thought about the option to choose my neighbour systematically but so I had somehow to keep track about the neighbours I already visited which seemed more complicated than to just choose them randomly. What is your opinion on that?

Answer (score 1):

I expect choosing a single neighbor systematically will work poorly.  Typical local search algorithms either look at multiple neighbors and choose the best (in which case you need more than one...) or repeatedly choose a random neighbor and decide whether to move there or stay where you are (in which case if you always choose the same neighbor, then you will quickly get stuck at a local optimum).  But you can do anything that works.